# Setting values to null, or starting values Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, ionic-framework

How to reset values of input to null, after click on some button?

Empty fields:

[image]

Fields with some values that i want to reset back to empty fields.

[image]

HTML:

```
    <label class="item item-input">
       <input id="tezina" type="number" placeholder="Tezina" ng-model="podaci.tezina">
       </label>
       <label class="item item-input">
       <input id="mamac" type="text" placeholder="Mamac" ng-model="podaci.mamac">
       </label>
       <label class="item item-input">
       <input id="pribor" type="text" placeholder="Pribor" ng-model="podaci.pribor">
       </label>+
<button class="button button-positive" ng-click="isprazniPolja()">Isprazni</button>
```

And i tried (not working), function from controller :

```
$scope.isprazniPolja = function() {
$scope.podaci= null;
```

}

Comment: can you make fiddle or codepen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want reset the values
You can do like this

```
$scope.isprazniPolja = function(){
          $scope.podaci.tezina="";
          $scope.podaci.mamac="";
          $scope.podaci.pribor="";
          }
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/TbNxXTO2nt1QX0rC99Gz?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring `podaci` as empty object

```
$scope.podaci= {};
```

**EDIT**

Also yo can try

```
$scope.podaci.tezina = null;
$scope.podaci.mamac= null;
$scope.podaci.pribor= null;
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is an object than

```
     $scope.podaci="";
```

If it is an array than

```
     $scope.podaci=[];
```